# How to combine h5 data numpy arrays based on date in filename?

Tags: python, numpy, glob, h5py, hdf

I have hundreds of .h5 files with dates in their filename (e.g ...20221017...). For each file, I have extracted some parameters into a numpy array of the format

```
[[param_1a, param_2a...param_5a],
  ... 
 [param_1x, param_2x,...param_5x]]
```

which represents data of interest. I want to group the data by month, so instead of having (e.g) 30 arrays for one month, I have 1 array which represents the average of the 30 arrays. How can I do this?

This is the code I have so far, filename represents a txt file of file names.

```
def combine_months(filename):
    fin = open(filename, 'r')
    next_name = fin.readline()
    while (next_name != ""):
        year = next_name[6:10]
        month = next_name[11:13]
        date = month+'\\'+year
        #not sure where to go from here
    fin.close()
```

An example of what I hope to achieve is that say array_1, array_2, array_3 are numpy arrays representing data from different h5 files with the same month in the date of their filename.

```
array_1 = [[ 1  4 10]
           [ 2  5 11]
           [3  6 12]]
array_2 = [[ 1  2 5]
           [ 2  2 3]
           [ 3  6 12]]
array_3 = [[ 2  4 10]
           [ 3  2 3]
           [ 4  6 12]]
```

I want the result to look like:

```
2022_04_data = [[1,3,7.5]
                [2, 2, 6.5]
                [3,4,7.5]
                [4,6,12]]
```

Note that the first number of each row represents an ID, so I need to group those data together based on the first number as well.

Comment: Are you using `fin = open(filename, 'r')` and `fin.readline()` to read the HDF5 files? If so, I don't see how that will work. You need to use a package that can read HDF5 files - h5py and pytables

Comment: I am using it to read a text file containing all the names of the hdf5 files

Comment: Please clarify your question: Do you need help 1) reading the data from the H5 files, or 2) averaging the extracted arrays based common row IDs? (or both?)

Comment: I know how to read the data from the h5 files, my question is since I have hundreds of h5 files, I want to combine the data as shown above based on the date in their filename.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the beginning of an answer. (I suspect you may have more questions as you work thru the details.)

There are several ways to get the filenames. You could put them in a file, but it's easier (and better IMHO) to use the `glob.iglob()` function. There are 2 examples below that show how to: 1) open each file, 2) read the data from the `data` dataset into an array, and 3) append the array to a list. The first example has the file names in a list. The second uses the `glob.iglob()` function to get the filenames. (You could also use `glob.glob()` to create a list of names.)

**Method 1: read filenames from list**

```
import h5py
arr_list = []
for h5file in ['20221001.h5', '20221002.h5', '20221003.h5']:    
    with h5py.File(h5file,'r') as h5f:    
        arr = h5f['data'][()]
        #print(arr)
        arr_list.append(arr)
```

**Method 2: use glob.iglob() to get files using wildcard names**

```
import h5py
from glob import iglob 
arr_list = []
for h5file in iglob('202210*.h5'):    
    with h5py.File(h5file,'r') as h5f:    
        print(h5f.keys()) # to get the dataset names from the keys
        arr = h5f['data'][()]
        #print(arr)
        arr_list.append(arr)
```

After you have read the datasets into arrays, you iterate over the list, do your calculations and create a new array from the results. Code below shows how to get the `shape` and `dtype`.

```
for arr in arr_list:
# do something with the data based on column 0 value
    print(arr.shape, arr.dtype)
```

Code below shows a way to sum rows with matching column 0 values. Without more details it's hard to show exactly how to do this. It reads all column 0 values into a sorted list, then uses to size count and sum arrays, then as a index to the proper row.

```
# first create a list from column 0 values, then sort
row_value_list = []
for arr in arr_list:
    col_vals = arr[:,0]
    for val in col_vals:
        if val not in row_value_list:
            row_value_list.append(val)
# Sort list of column IDs
row_value_list.sort()

# get length index list to create cnt and sum arrays
a0 = len(row_value_list) 
# get shape and dtype from 1st array, assume constant for all
a1 = arr_list[0].shape[1] 
dt = arr_list[0].dtype

arr_cnt = np.zeros(shape=(a0,a1),dtype=dt)
arr_cnt[:,0] = row_value_list
arr_sum = np.zeros(shape=(a0,a1),dtype=dt)
arr_sum[:,0] = row_value_list
for arr in arr_list:
    for row in arr:
        idx = row_value_list.index(row[0])
        arr_cnt[idx,1:] += 1
        arr_sum[idx,1:] += row[1:]
        
print('Count Array\n',arr_cnt)
print('Sum Array\n',arr_sum)

arr_ave = arr_sum/arr_cnt
arr_ave[:,0] = row_value_list
print('Average Array\n',arr_ave)
```

Here is an alternate way to create `row_value_list` from a set. It's simpler because sets don't retain duplicate values, so you don't have to check for existing values when adding them to `row_value_set`.

```
# first create a set from column 0 values, then create a sorted list
row_value_set = set()
for arr in arr_list:
    col_vals = set(arr[:,0])
    row_value_set = row_value_set.union(col_vals)
row_value_list = sorted(row_value_set)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have a question though. For the 2nd method, let's say I have a hundred hdf5 files I want to read. How does the 2nd method read all of them? What does the '202210*.h5' represent?

Comment: glob is perfect to get 100 filenames. :-) Way easier than creating a list or a file with the names. It finds files that match a specified pattern (e.g. wildcards): `?` matches any 1 character, `*` matches any # of characters and `[]` matches a range of characters. For a stricter wildcard, you might use '202210??.h5' or '202210[0-9][0-9].h5'. See [glob docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for details.

Comment: I'm confused on what exactly 'data' represents? Also I am still stuck on how to iterate over the list of arrays and create a new array from the results

Comment: HDF5 stores arrays in datasets. `'data'` is the name of the dataset in my example H5 file. A dataset can have most any name. Your answer said you knew how to extract the array data. Do you need help on this? You can get the dataset names by looping on the group keys. Once you have the arrays in a list, you can loop over the list, create new data and save to another array. I will add this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. Is there a way to do median values instead of average values?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. NumPy has a function to do it: ` np.median()` However, it's trickier. You will have to createa an array with all the values, then do the calculation on a row by row basis (use the `axis=` parameter) and exclude the index in column 0. I would have to study this a lot more to get it working.

Comment: Calculating the median would be easy if you just want the median of all values along 1 axis. Filtering first to get matching group id values (in column 0) made that a lot harder starting from my first answer. (I tried, and it quickly got complicated and hard to follow.) New answer posted that calculates mean and median.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new, updated answer that addresses the comment/request about calculating the median. (It also calculates the mean, and can be easily extended to calculate other statistics from the masked array.)

As noted in my comment on Nov 4 2022, "*starting from my first answer quickly got complicated and hard to follow*". This process is similar but different from the first answer. It uses `glob` to get a list of filenames (instead of `iglob`). Instead of loading the H5 datasets into a list of arrays, it loads all of the data into a single array (data is "stacked" on the 0-axis.). I don't think this increases the memory footprint. However, memory could be a problem if you load a lot of very large datasets for analysis.

Summary of the procedure:

1. Use `glob.glob()` to load filenames to a list based on a wildcard
2. Allocate an array to hold all the data (`arr_all`) based on the # of
   files and size of 1 dataset.
3. Loop thru all H5 files, loading data to `arr_all`
4. Create a sorted list of unique group IDs (column 0 values)
5. Allocate arrays to hold mean/median (`arr_mean` and `arr_median`) based on the # of unique row IDs and # of columns in `arr_all`.
6. Loop over values in ID list, then:
   a. Create masked array (`mask`) where column 0 value = loop value
   b. Broadcast `mask` to match `arr_all` shape then apply to create `ma_arr_all`
   c. Loop over columns of `ma_arr_all`, compress to get unmasked values, then calculate mean and median and save.

Code below:

```
import h5py
from glob import glob 
import numpy as np

#  use glob.glob() to get list of files using wildcard names
file_list = glob('202210*.h5')
with h5py.File(file_list[0],'r') as h5f:
    a0, a1 = h5f['data'].shape
    # allocate array to hold values from all datasets
    arr_all = np.zeros(shape=(len(file_list)*a0,a1), dtype=h5f['data'].dtype)
        
start, stop = 0, a0
for i, h5file in enumerate(file_list):    
    with h5py.File(h5file,'r') as h5f:       
        arr_all[start:stop,:] = h5f['data'][()]
        start += a0
        stop += a0

# Create a set from column 0 values, and use to create a sorted list
row_value_list = sorted(set(arr_all[:,0]))

arr_mean = np.zeros(shape=(len(row_value_list),arr_all.shape[1]))
arr_median = np.zeros(shape=(len(row_value_list),arr_all.shape[1]))

col_0 = arr_all[:,0:1]
for i, row_val in enumerate(row_value_list):
    row_mask = np.where(col_0==row_val, False, True ) # True mask value ignores data.
    all_mask= np.broadcast_to(row_mask, arr_all.shape)
    ma_arr_all = np.ma.masked_array(arr_all, mask=all_mask)    
    for j in range(ma_arr_all.shape[1]):
        masked_col = ma_arr_all[:,j:j+1].compressed()
        arr_mean[i:i+1,j:j+1] = np.mean(masked_col)
        arr_median[i:i+1,j:j+1] = np.median(masked_col)
print('Mean values:\n',arr_mean)    
print('Median values:\n',arr_median)
```

Added Nov 22, 2022:
Method above uses `np.broadcast_to()` introduced in NumPy 1.10. Here is an alternate method for prior versions. (Replaces the entire `for i, row_val` loop.) It should be more memory efficient. I haven't profiled to verify, but arrays `all_mask` and `ma_arr_all` are not created.

```
for i, row_val in enumerate(row_value_list):
    row_mask = np.where(col_0==row_val, False, True ) # True mask value ignores data.  
    for j in range(arr_all.shape[1]):
        masked_col = np.ma.masked_array(arr_all[:,j:j+1], mask=row_mask).compressed()
        arr_mean[i:i+1,j:j+1] = np.mean(masked_col)
        arr_median[i:i+1,j:j+1] = np.median(masked_col)
```

I ran with values provided by OP. Output is provided below and is the same for both methods:

```
Mean values:
 [[ 1.          3.          7.5       ]
 [ 2.          3.66666667  8.        ]
 [ 3.          4.66666667  9.        ]
 [ 4.          6.         12.        ]]
Median values:
 [[ 1.   3.   7.5]
 [ 2.   4.  10. ]
 [ 3.   6.  12. ]
 [ 4.   6.  12. ]]
```

Comment: I ran this code, and replaced h5f['data'] with my helper function that extracts the data of the file and returns an array. But I get the Attribute Error 'File' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I don't know why you are getting this error. The term `'encode'` doesn't appear in my answers. What line causes the error, and which File object is it trying to read?

Comment: I've fixed that error, now I've gotten another one. When np.broadcast_to is called, I get 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'broadcast_to'

Comment: Not sure what could cause that error. Are you using `import numpy as np`? Numpy's `broadcast_to()` function was added in version 1.10. The current version is 1.23, so it was added a long time ago.

Comment: Would there be another way without using broadcast_to? I'm using python 2.7.5. Is there also a way to check which version I have downloaded?

Comment: Well, that explains that. I'm using Python 3 and NumPy 1.22.2. You can get module versions with `import module ; module.__version__`, where "module" is the name of your module (like numpy, h5py, etc)

Comment: `numpy.__version__` returns the numpy version. It will display in the window if you run in the command interpreter. If running from a file you need to `print numpy.__version__`. Also, I used `broadcast_to()` because it was convenient. You can code it other ways. It uses the (N,1) mask array (`row_mask`) to create a (N,M) mask array (`all_mask`); where every column is identical. You can create `all_mask` another way, or apply `row_mask` 1 column at a time.

Comment: After looking at the code, it was easy to eliminate `np.broadcast_to()`. Even better, it simplifies the code logic and should reduce the memory footprint. Replace the entire `for i, row_val` loop with the new code segment.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. Once I ran this code for different months, is there a way to combine them into one? I want to make one large pandas dataframe such that the first column is id, second is 202210, 202211, 202212, etc.... where the ids are sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if it completely works. After I ran the first loop, it essentially just filled arr_all with the values from the first file repeated in all the rows

Comment: I ran this using the sample data you provided saved in 3 files. Calculated Mean and Median matched expected values. (I will add them to the answer.) Regarding pandas, you can create a dataframe with values from the resulting arrays `arr_mean` and`arr_median`. More details would go beyond the scope of this question. Post as a new question.